# Mongoose return array from find method

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, momentjs

I'm trying to query a collection within my Mongo database. I'm quite new to Mongo (coming from Laravel and normal relational dbs) and am finding it a little challenging to get results from the db.

I've got a collection called `cars` and I have over 1,000 documents in that collection, I'd like to return an array of cars which I could then loop over or do traditional JS magic with, I'm trying to return an array of cars from 3 hours ago based on a `created_at` field that I added....

```js
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECTION, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, () => console.log('connected'))
const db = mongoose.connection

const threeHoursAgo = moment(new Date()).subtract({hours: 2})
db.collection('cars').find({ 'created_at': { $gte: threeHoursAgo } }).then((res) => {
  console.log(res) // no array items???
})
```

My implementation doesn't seem to give me any results at all other that some big generic object with what would appear to be Mongo DB schema with things like a `cmd` object and `options` object etc...

What am I missing?

It's also worth noting, I do not have a Model for my data since that's one of the reasons of switching to Mongo DB rather than something like SQL, so just need to use `db.collection()` and then query things like this

Answer (score 0):

I think that your query is not returning any results because you're passing the moment object as it is. You need to convert the date contained in it into something that Mongo can understand using **.toDate()** as stated in the [moment documenation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/):

`const threeHoursAgo = moment(new Date()).subtract({hours: 2}).toDate()`

Comment: My `created_at` field for my documents is stored with `new Date()` whatever format that returns. Updated and tested though, still doesn't give me my results other than as described. Ideally I just want to return an array of all of my items in `res`, that's what I would've thought it would do.

Comment: So, you're writing the `created_at` yourself instead of using mongoose's timestamps? If I follow correctly, then `created_at` is a Date object and you are comparing it to a Moment object. It looks like you're not only comparing objects here, but you're comparing different kinds of objects. The method I provided in my answer should work for the `createdAt` timestamp (I use it for my queries). If for some reason you need to use your created_at, add `.getTime()` to the variable before you store it

Comment: Okay, but even if I drop the query based on time time, I still get nothing with `find()`, want an array back